# Why instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server in somee host

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-hosting

I upload my web site and database in somee host , somee host give me connection string :

```
workstation id=ASPNETDB1.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=*****;pwd=****;data source=ASPNETDB1.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=ASPNETDB1
```

In localhost my connection string is :

```
 <add name="ASPNETDBConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I change my connection string :

```
<add name="ASPNETDBConnectionString1" connectionString="workstation id=ASPNETDB1.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=*****;pwd=*****;data source=ASPNETDB1.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=ASPNETDB1"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I try too :

```
  <add name="ConnectionString1" connectionString="server=ASPNETDB1.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=****;pwd=****;data source=ASPNETDB1.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=ASPNETDB1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But when I login in my website show this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Can you please help me to find out what is wrong in this scenario?

Comment: I see that you have correct details. I think you should ask the correct connection string with your current provider.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005/
In yours connectionstring seem that the server ip address or name is missing:

```
Server=<******myServerAddress*****>;Database=ASPNETDB;User Id=******;Password=*****;
```

Comment: my database created by sql server 2008r2

Comment: The connection string is identical: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/